# Connection between two connection forms defined on different frames

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

> Let $(M,g)$ be be a Riemannian manifold of dimension 2. Prove that if $E_1,E_2$, $\bar{E_1},\bar{E_2}$ are two different frames, then $\omega_1^{2}=\bar\omega_1^{2}+d\varphi$, where $\omega_1^2$ is the connection form on $E_1,E_2$, $\bar\omega_1^2$ is the connection form on $\bar{E_1},\bar{E_2}$ and $\varphi$ is the $0$-form (smooth function) that for each $p\in M$ returns the angle between $E_1(p)$ and $\bar {E_1}(p)$.

My attempt:

I was able to prove that since $E_1,E_2$ is an orthonormal basis (for each $p\in M$) for $T_pM$, then $\bar{E_1}=cos(\varphi)E_1+sin(\varphi)E_2$ and $\bar{E_2}=-sin(\varphi)E_1+cos(\varphi)E_2$, but I don't know how to reach the final conclusion.

Edit:

$\omega_1^{2}=d\theta_1(E_1,E_2)\theta_1+d\theta_2(E_1,E_2)\theta_2\\
\bar{\omega}_1^{2}=d\bar{\theta_1}(\bar{E_1},\bar{E_2})\bar{\theta_1}+d\bar{\theta_2}(\bar{E_1},\bar{E_2})\bar{\theta_2}$

Where $\theta_1,\theta_2,\bar\theta_2,\bar\theta_1$ are the corresponding dual basis (depending on $p\in M$).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to get further than this. Edit to include the definitions of $\omega_1^2$ and $\tilde\omega_1^2$. How are your equations relevant?

Comment: That was a hint, but maybe theres another way

Comment: There's no alternative to knowing what the basic objects are. Relating $\omega_1^2$ to $\bar{\omega}_1^2$ shouldn't be hard once you know what they are. Relevant formulas for the change of frame (in any dimension) are probably easily found in your textbook, but this is somehow not the point.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I edited the post so it'll be clearer what they are. But I'm still not sure how to connect them

Comment: How are the dual basis forms related if you know how the frames are related? So you do not understand that $\omega_1^2 = dE_1\cdot E_2$? Why do you write $\omega_1^2$ but write $\theta_1$ rather than $\theta^1$, etc.